# std::packaged_task::reset example from http://www.cplusplus.com doesn't work

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11, clang

I tried to compile and run example of reset() function from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/packaged_task/reset/:

```
$ cat task.cpp
// packaged_task::get_future
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <utility>      // std::move
#include <future>       // std::packaged_task, std::future
#include <thread>       // std::thread

// a simple task:
int triple (int x) { return x*3; }

int main ()
{
  std::packaged_task<int(int)> tsk (triple); // package task

  std::future<int> fut = tsk.get_future();
  std::thread (std::move(tsk),33).detach();
  std::cout << "The triple of 33 is " << fut.get() << ".\n";

  // re-use same task object:
  tsk.reset();
  fut = tsk.get_future();
  std::thread(std::move(tsk),99).detach();
  std::cout << "Thre triple of 99 is " << fut.get() << ".\n";

  return 0;
}
```

but I got either compiler error or runtime error, depending on compiler used:

- GCC:

`$ g++ -o task -std=c++11 -I/opt/local/include task.cpp && ./task
The triple of 33 is 99.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
  what():  No associated state
[1]    14850 abort      ./task`

- CLANG:

`$ clang++ -o task -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -I/opt/local/include task.cpp && ./task
In file included from task.cpp:2:
In file included from /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
In file included from /opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:627:
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1627:45: error: multiple overloads of 'address' instantiate to the same
      signature 'const_pointer (const_reference) const noexcept'
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY const_pointer address(const_reference __x) const _NOEXCEPT
                                            ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:922:38: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::allocator<int (int)>' requested here
    : public integral_constant<bool, __is_empty(_Tp)> {};
                                     ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1908:40: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::is_empty<std::__1::allocator<int (int)> >' requested here
                                bool = is_empty<_T2>::value
                                       ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1930:44: note: in instantiation of default argument for
      '__libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)>, false, false>' required here
template <class _T1, class _T2, unsigned = __libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<_T1, _T2>::value>
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2298:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for
      '__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)> >' required here
    : private __libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<_T1, _T2>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:1770:36: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__compressed_pair<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)> >' requested here
    __compressed_pair<_Fp, _Alloc> __f_;
                                   ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:1877:9: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__packaged_task_func<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)>, int (int)>' requested here
    if (sizeof(_FF) <= sizeof(__buf_))
        ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2026:45: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__packaged_task_function<int (int)>::__packaged_task_function<int (&)(int)>' requested here
        explicit packaged_task(_Fp&& __f) : __f_(_VSTD::forward<_Fp>(__f)) {}
                                            ^
task.cpp:12:32: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::packaged_task<int
      (int)>::packaged_task<int (&)(int), void>' requested here
  std::packaged_task<int(int)> tsk (triple); // package task
                               ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1625:39: note: previous declaration is here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY pointer address(reference __x) const _NOEXCEPT
                                      ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2121:9: error: data member instantiated with function type 'int (int)'
    _T1 __first_;
        ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2298:15: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)>, 2>' requested here
    : private __libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<_T1, _T2>
              ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:1770:36: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__compressed_pair<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)> >' requested here
    __compressed_pair<_Fp, _Alloc> __f_;
                                   ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:1877:9: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__packaged_task_func<int (int), std::__1::allocator<int (int)>, int (int)>' requested here
    if (sizeof(_FF) <= sizeof(__buf_))
        ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2026:45: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__packaged_task_function<int (int)>::__packaged_task_function<int (&)(int)>' requested here
        explicit packaged_task(_Fp&& __f) : __f_(_VSTD::forward<_Fp>(__f)) {}
                                            ^
task.cpp:12:32: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::packaged_task<int
      (int)>::packaged_task<int (&)(int), void>' requested here
  std::packaged_task<int(int)> tsk (triple); // package task
                               ^
2 errors generated.`

I'm using OSX Maverics and compilers:

`$ g++ --version
g++ (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.2_0) 4.8.2`

`$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix`

Could someone please help me?

Comment: I've got the same gcc error, I've also tried to wait the future. I'm playing here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb3c75190821f03 if anyone has any idea can modify the code.

Comment: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17819 for Clang/libc++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is correct:

```
std::thread (std::move(tsk),33).detach(); // 1
//...
tsk.reset();  // 2
```

After (1), `tsk` has no more state (per [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) of `packaged_task`)

At (2), `reset()` is [required to throw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/reset) the no_state `std::future_error`

clang had a bug, as pointed out in the comments.